# How to align QProgressBar in the center in status bar and show text?

Tags: qt

I am showing progress bar in status bar but it not really aligned well. I would like it to show up center aligned if possible or at least have some margin on the left, I am attaching a snapshot.

The 2nd issue I have is I want it to display the text but text is not showing.

```
_progressBar = new QProgressBar(this);

_progressBar->setRange(0, 0);
_progressBar->setTextVisible(true);
_progressBar->setFormat("Connecting");

ui->statusBar->addPermanentWidget( _progressBar, 2 );
```

Since we are at it, the stretch parameter (in ctor) has default value of 0 but it doesn't really say what other values it could have. `0` producess the shortest size and any other value great than 0 I tried gives the maximum. there is nothing in the middle. I tried to fix issue with `stretch`value but not succescful.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First issue:**
If you want to add some space at the left of the progress bar, you can use a `QSpacerItem`. Wrap this `QSpacerItem` and the `QProgressBar` inside a `QWidget`, then add this `QWidget` in the status bar:

```
QProgressBar * _progressBar = new QProgressBar();
_progressBar->setRange(1, 10);
_progressBar->setValue(2);
_progressBar->setTextVisible(true);
_progressBar->setFormat("Connecting");

QWidget * w = new QWidget;
QHBoxLayout * _hlayout = new QHBoxLayout();
_hlayout->addSpacerItem(new QSpacerItem(40,1));
_hlayout->addWidget(_progressBar);
w->setLayout(_hlayout);

ui->statusBar->addPermanentWidget(w, 2);
```

[image]

.
**Second issue:**
Your text will be displayed once you call `QProgressBar::setValue` with a value inside the range you specified:

```
QProgressBar * _progressBar = new QProgressBar();

_progressBar->setRange(0, 100);
_progressBar->setValue(10);
_progressBar->setTextVisible(true);
_progressBar->setFormat("Connecting");

ui->statusBar->addPermanentWidget( _progressBar, 2 );
```

By the way, the empty margin at the right of the bar is where the text is displayed.
If you want to get rid of that space, you can add `_progressBar->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);` to center your text over the `QProgressBar`:
  [image]

Comment: thanks, I will try this out in the morning but can I display text on the progress bar itself and kill the space on the right? This is what I would like.

Comment: Hi. I've updated the answer: to display the text over the progress bar itself, you can use: `_progressBar->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);`.